# Ice, snow, glacial data for ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, web-service

I'm quite new to this field, so forgive the amateur question, but are there any WMS or WTS that can provide a historical representation of ice melt in the Artic/Greenland area? I'm using ArcGIS Online as map builder and I'm having a difficult time finding any time-based presentation images or graphics.

Comment: Jakobshavn Glacier Retreat (WMS) http://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/details.cgi?aid=3140 link to wms

Comment: That's pretty close, but it doesn't load based on my base map.

Comment: Change the CRS to the one you have http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html#coordinate-systems-and-axis-orientation

Answer (score 1):

The National Snow and Ice Data Center provide OGC Web Services including WMS detailing coverage from their Arctic Atlas products.

Their [service details](http://nsidc.org/data/atlas/ogc_services.html) lists the WMS, WFS and Web Coverage Service endpoints.

The website notes some issues with the system at the moment, an alternate data source could be the [NASA Earth Observations WMS](http://neowms.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/wms/wms) includes remotely sensed [snow & ice coverage products](http://neowms.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/view.php?datasetId=SCSIE_W) from the MODIS satellites.